# Ransack: Conditions on both a child, and its respective grandchild record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Don't be intimidated by the length. It's probably actually quite simple.I couldn't find an answer, though I tried looking everywhere. I hope this is a good enough challenge for you.

Here goes:

```
Panel.rb
    has_many :status_dates
    has_many :statuses, through: :status_dates

StatusDate.rb
    belongs_to :status
    belongs_to :panel

    def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
            %w( current ) + _ransackers.keys
    end

Status.rb
    has_many :status_dates
```

Here is the schema.

```
create_table "panels", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "no"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

create_table "status_dates", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "status_id"
    t.integer  "panel_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.date     "date"
    t.boolean  "current"
  end

  add_index "status_dates", ["panel_id"], name: "index_status_dates_on_panel_id"
  add_index "status_dates", ["status_id"], name: "index_status_dates_on_status_id"

  create_table "statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

**What do I want to do**?

I want to identify a parent record based on **two** conditions which must **both** simultaneously exist exist on: (i) a child record and (ii) in turn, that child's, child record too (i.e. a grand child record).

**What does that mean?**

Suppose we have:

[image]

I want to find all panels, where there is a particular StatusDate record such that StatusDate.current = y, and its respective child, Status.name = x.

(“Current” is actually a boolean value on the StatusDate record.)

**What is happening at the moment?**

Here is my _condition_fields.html.erb partial:

**What is the problem?**

Right now, ransack applies those conditions across different records. But I want them applied directly to: (I) a child record and (ii) that particular child's child record as well.

Any idea how I can do this?

Assistance very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try query following way:

```
Panel.ransack({StatusDate_current:0, StatusDate_Status_name: "Installed"})
```

Comment: would you know how i can access those variables from params?

Comment: You mean request params? You need to pass the value for `StatusDate_current `  and `StatusDate_Status_name ` in params, no?

Comment: It's trickier when the actual values are nested, haven't worked that out yet. I'm still looking into it. i'll come back and post the answer when found. appreciate the help.